# mysql Select values from multiple different columns values into single column(PIVOT)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

```
+---------+------+--------+------+
|   year   | id  | band  | score | 
+---------+------+--------+------+
|    1990  |  1  | a     |  10  |
|    1991  | 1   | b     |  20  |
|    1992  | 1   | c     |  30  |
|    1993  | 1   | d     |  40  |
|    1994  | 1   | e     |  40  |
+---------+------+--------+------+
```

I want output like below

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----
| id    | 1990  | 1991  | 1992  |1993  | 1994 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------
|  1    |  10(a) | 20(b) | 30(c)| 40(d)| 50(e)|
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Postgres <> SQLite! Pleas tag only the one database you are running.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the statement as follows:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ''',
      year,
      ''' then concat(score,''','(''',',band,',''')',''') end) year_',
      year
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  mytable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM mytable 
                   GROUP BY id');
select @sql;


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8NNj8zrvRPQqj5Gf5idq6f/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation. I think that it makes more sense to put the bands and scores in separate columns, so:

```
select id,
    max(case when year = 1990 then score end) score_1990,
    max(case when year = 1990 then band  end) band_1990,
    max(case when year = 1991 then score end) score_1991,
    max(case when year = 1991 then band  end) band_1991,
    ...
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: Hey , thanks for your reply .What if we have  50k ids having band and score values for the last 50 years.

Comment: @sakthi.nagulsamy: you need one (actually, two) expressions per year, that's how conditional aggregation works. Otherwise, you need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.